# Python Image Library - Convert pixels to 2D list

Tags: python, list, python-imaging-library

I need to perform some operations on a 2D array of values read from an image, and then create an image with a resulting 2D array. I'm using python lists to represent the 2D array.

Something very odd is happening; the values in the 2D array (list of lists) appear to become "0" at some point between the two print calls I have labeled. That is, they seem to be read correctly from the image... but then somehow get set to zero.

Code:

```
image = Image.open("test.png").convert("L")

data = [ [255] * image.size[1] ] * image.size[0]
pix = image.load()
for x in range(0, image.size[0]):
    for y in range(0, image.size[1]):
        data[x][y] = pix[x, y]
        #data[x][y] = 77
        print "1. data[x][y] = " + str(data[x][y]) + " .vs. " + str(pix[x, y]) # Prints correct values

for x in range(0, image.size[0]):
    for y in range(0, image.size[1]):
        print "2. data[x][y] = " + str(data[x][y]) + " .vs. " + str(pix[x, y]) # Always prints "0 .vs. [correct value]"
```

However, if I comment out the line

```
data[x][y] = pix[x, y]
```

And uncomment:

```
data[x][y] = 77
```

Then the two print statements show that all elements in data are 77

What is going on? I'm not an expert on python, but I can't think of any sensible reason why list values would change like that.

I have tried the following line, in case the pixel accessor is doing something wierd:

```
data[x][y] = 0 + int(pix[x, y])
```

But still get the same result. I've also tried using RGB images instead of greyscale.

I should make it clear that I am definitely not doing anything with data between those two print calls. The code above is exactly what I have reduced my original program to (after discovering that all my "results" image files were black).

Comment: Why can't you simply operate on the 2D structure returned by image.load()?

Comment: The data gets modified in place by an algorithm later on. Also it will contain complex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're problem is with this line:

```
data = [ [255] * image.size[1] ] * image.size[0]
```

This creates a list of length `image.size[1]` filled with the value `255`.  Then you create `image.size[0]` references to *the same list* and pack all of those references into another list.  So, when you change `a[1][1]`, you also change `a[0][1]` and `a[2][1]` etc. because `a[0]`,`a[1]`,`a[2]`, `...` are references to *the same list*.

Here's a quick example:

```
a = [[255]*10]*10
a[1][1] = 77
print (a)
```

The easiest workaround is:

```
a = [[255]*10 for _ in range(10)]
```

As this creates 10 new lists instead of a list of references to the same list.

Comment: In python, the variable `_` isn't special -- It's just somewhat customary to use it to say "Syntactically, I need a variable here, but I'm never actually going to use it"

Comment: I'd like to add: While this answer is correct, creating an entire list of lists in advance is not a good idea. If the data-size is known in advance, a numpy.array might be preferable. Otherwise, dynamically append to the list as @halex points out below.

Comment: @Dhara -- I don't see any problem with creating the data structure in advance if you're going to fill it immediately.  (What reason do you have for saying that it isn't a good idea?)  A numpy array would definitely be better if numpy is necessary for other pieces of the project, but sometimes it's preferable to avoid the external dependency if you plan for others to use your code (but definitely a good point to consider).

Comment: because you iterate twice through the list -- once to create it and then again when adding each data item. I suppose it is more efficient  (and definitely IMO more elegant) to simply append to an empty list. If you want to avoid the external dependancy, I understand that the built in array module can also be quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

You better change `data` to `data = []` and append every row.

```
data = []
pix = image.load()
for y in xrange(image.size[1]):
    data.append([pix[x, y] for x in xrange(image.size[0])])
```

Comment: Do image arrays support slicing like numpy arrays?  If so, you could do `data.append(list(pix[:,y]))`